# Unicode to String Python 2

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-2.x

I am trying to convert an plain string into the special character to work it in my logic in python 2.

```
word = 'Tb\u03b1'
word = unicode('Tb\u03b1')

if word.encode('utf-8') == u'Tb\u03b1'.encode('utf-8'):
    print 'They are equals'

print word.encode('utf-8')
print type(word.encode('utf-8'))
print u'Tb\u03b1'.encode('utf-8')
print type(u'Tb\u03b1'.encode('utf-8'))
```

I am getting this response

```
Tb\u03b1
<type 'str'>
Tbα
<type 'str'>
```

My question is... As I apply the `unicode` method to the word, I am not supposed to have the same response in line 1 and 3? I would like to get the line 3 because I need to do some logic based on that special character

Comment: Why do you have the string `'Tb\u03b1'`? Are you sure that's what you have in your actual program? There aren't many sensible ways you could come to have that string, and you should probably change whatever code is producing it instead of trying to post-process the output.

Comment: Not sure what you want, you already know how to get the line 3.

Comment: It is coming as a `string` from a json file like this `{'word': 'Tb\u03b1'}`. However the unicode is not important for me but it is the special character it tries to represent. That unicode could be in any part of the string (beginning, middle, end). So what I want is to convert that string coming from the json as a variable, to the real string representation

Comment: @user2288043: Use `json.loads`, and this problem instantly vanishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\u` has no special meaning in a non-unicode literal, so it remains as `\u` in your string. To interpret the `\u` escapes and produce the corresponding Unicode, use the encoding `"unicode_escape"`:

```
>>> as_str = "\u03b1"
>>> as_unicode = as_str.decode(encoding="unicode_escape")
>>> print as_unicode
α
```

But you'd be better off if you could figure out a way to avoid being in this situation. Even better, switch to Python 3 where these kinds of things make a lot more sense.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!. I will take your advice in consideration :)